# Advice contacting the IRS? Refund still pending from 2019

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs

My girlfriend filed electronically in March 2020 for her federal taxes for 2019. The IRS "where's my refund" page showed "your taxes are being processed" for 8 months, then in November changed to "we cannot find a tax filing for you".  She has attempted to contact the IRS and the Tax Advocacy Office more than 20 times, always receiving a recording but never able to contact anyone.

She has since received her 2020 refund, but no 2019 refund.

Is there anything we can do short of hiring an attorney?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

She could try getting an in-person appointment at her local [Taxpayer Assistance Center](https://www.irs.gov/help/contact-your-local-irs-office) (TAC).

Although the IRS does not mention it, one [article](https://www.thebalance.com/contact-the-irs-1289982) states that you can write a letter to the director of your local TAC. You could mail a printout of the "Where's My Refund" screen along with a copy of her 2019 return and a cover letter explaining the situation.

Separately, she can contact her US [Representative](https://www.house.gov/representatives) or [Senator](https://www.senate.gov/senators/senators-contact.htm) under Constituent Issues/Services and tell them she is still awaiting her 2019 refund and can't get through to the IRS or the Advocate by phone.